# Invalid operation at current cursor position when trying to run sql statement

Tags: java, sql

I tried to retrieve a row of data from the database but its give me an error Invalid operation at current cursor position.

Below is this sample in my database

ID      Continent       Country State   Landmark

81  Asia            Japan   Osaka    Universal Studios Japan

```
...public static void main(String[] args) {
   LocationDA locate = new LocationDA();
   ResultSet rs =  locate.getRecord("81");
   try{
       System.out.println(rs.getString(5));
   }catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }
}


public ResultSet getRecord(String id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE ID = ?";
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    return rs;
}
```

Assuming all the connection has been declared and I have my data in my database. My getRecord() is inside a class name LocationDA. My ID inside database is declared as varchar and it is primary key. Where is my error and how can I solve it?

Comment: The JavaDoc for [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) says (in part) *A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method `next` makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
try{
       rs.next();
       System.out.println(rs.getString("5"));

   }catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage("5"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your connection opening at? You shouldn't be keeping your connection open indefinitely or needlessly. Your resultset is not calling its next() function so you aren't iterating to the data. You shouldn't be passing resultsets through public methods however (or in general imho). Instead create a class to represent the data within the result set and load the resultset into said object (which you then return).

Try instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocationDA locate = new LocationDA();
    Record record =  locate.getRecord("81");
    try{
        System.out.println(record.getLandmark());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(record.getMessage());
    }
 }


public ResultSet getRecord(String id) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM LOCATION WHERE ID = ?";

    try (Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection()){
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setContinent(rs.getString(2));
            //etc.
            return record;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can change it to suit your needs (e.g not return null);